# NHibernate multiple subqueries with in clause

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have a following working SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM truck t
WHERE t.currentlocationdbid IN (SELECT dbid FROM location WHERE name = 'Los Angeles')
OR t.nextdestinationdbid IN (SELECT dbid FROM location WHERE name = 'Chicago' OR name = 'New York');
```

I'd like to write this in NHibernate. With multiple trips to DB for each entity it works, of course, but I'd like to make it a one trip. Looked into examples with detached queries like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284700/nhibernate-queryover-subquery), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530018/nhibernate-subquery-with-multiple-columns-join) or [this](http://www.andrewwhitaker.com/blog/2014/10/24/queryover-series-part-8-working-with-subqueries/) but none worked for me. Tried to do it also with aliases and criterias.

One of dozens of attempts:

```
var subQuery1 = QueryOver.Of<LocationEntity>().Where(l => l.Name == LocationNameEnum.LA);
var subQuery2 = QueryOver.Of<LocationEntity>().Where(l => l.Name == LocationNameEnum.CHG || l.Name == LocationNameEnum.NY);

var poc = session.QueryOver<TruckEntity>()
                 .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(t => t.CurrentLocation).In(subQuery1)
                 .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(t => t.NextDestination).In(subQuery2)
                 .List<TruckEntity>();
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it almost right, you are only missing the `.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()...)` for the `or` in SQL.

Based on your code (assuming that you have a property `Id` in `LocationEntity`):

```
// get IDs to look for in CurrentLocation
var subQuery1 = QueryOver.Of<LocationEntity>()
    .Where(l => l.Name == LocationNameEnum.LA)
    .Select(x => x.Id);

// get IDs to look for in NextDestination
var subQuery2 = QueryOver.Of<LocationEntity>()
    .Where(l => l.Name == LocationNameEnum.CHG || l.Name == LocationNameEnum.NY)
    .Select(x => x.Id);

var poc = session.QueryOver<TruckEntity>()
    .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction() // this takes care of the OR
        .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<TruckEntity>(x => x.CurrentLocation.Id).In(subQuery1))
        .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<TruckEntity>(x => x.NextDestination.Id).In(subQuery2))
    )
    .List<TruckEntity>();
```